# HTTPS protocol not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, packages

Steps taken on Ubuntu 18.04 server:

1. Updated package lists: `sudo apt update`
2. Reinstalled `curl`

   - After reinstalling, HTTPS protocol was enabled, but `php-fpm` package got uninstalled and wiped out all my wordpress sites

   ```
   curl: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)

   curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0

   Release-Date: 2018-01-24
   Protocols:    dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp 
   Features:     AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile UnixSockets PSL
   ```